# Add User Control to asp.net pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, asp-usercontrols

I create a user control with an event like this :

```
public partial class Person : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public delegate void EditPersonHandler(object sender, EditPersonEventArgs e);
    public event EditPersonHandler EditPerson;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

and this is my EditPersonEventArgs :

```
 public  class EditPersonEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    private int id;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public EditPersonEventArgs(int ID)
    {
        id = ID;
    }

}
```

And now i want to add this User control to my page and i do this :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UControl" TagName="UControlPerson" Src="~/SimpleUC/Person.ascx" %>

<div>
    <UControl:UControlPerson ID="UControlPerson" runat="server"
                             OnEditPerson="UControlPerson_EditPerson" />
</div>
```

and this my Function to handle the `OnSavePerson` :

```
protected void UControlPerson_EditPerson(object sender, EditPersonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I built the solution.
but when I render the page i get this error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this
request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code 
appropriately. 


Compiler Error Message: CS0426: The type name 'SimpleUC' does not exist in the type 
'System.Web.UI.UserControl'
```

this is my name space:
 `namespace UserControl.SimpleUC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a namespace conflict, the `UserControl` part of your user control namespace `UserControl.SimpleUC` is being resolved as the name space `System.Web.UI.UserControl`.

The easiest way to resolve this issue would be to choose another namespace for your control. Possibly something similar like `UserControls.SimpleUC`